# Laravel 5 Customexception

Tags: php, exception, laravel-5

I'm playing around with Laravel5 to test out custom exception. 
But It returns the error

> Call to a member function send() on string

and I can't really figure out why.

1.routes.php

[image: routes.php]

2.App/Exceptions/toshikiER.php

[image: App\Exceptions\toshikiER.php]

3.composer.php

[image: composer.json]

4.App/Exceptions/Hanlder.php

[image: App\Exceptions\Handler.php]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look at the render method annotations.

```
/**
 * Render an exception into a response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Exception  $e
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
```

You'll see that you have to return a \Illuminate\Htttp\Response.

I made my own exception too, I handle my new exception like this

```
return response()->view("your.view", [], 403);
```